# What does Segmentation fault (core dumped) actually mean?

Tags: warning-messages, linux, error-tracking

```
Block[
    {a, primes, tot, $RecursionLimit = Infinity},
    primes = Select[Range[10^9, 10^9 + 10^3], PrimeQ];
    tot = 0;
    Do[
        a[1] = 1;
        a[n_] := a[n] = Mod[6 a[n - 1]^2 + 10 a[n - 1] + 3, primes[[i]]];
        tot += a[10^5];
        Clear[a],
        {i, Length@primes}
    ];
    tot
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I got this error (from linux):

[image]

Same code in windows, it just stopped and quit from kernel. Does not give any error.

Comment: Do you want a http://unix.stackexchange.com type answer or a *Mathematica* answer?  We call it a kernel crash.  If you're using the Front End, you don't see this message when it happens (at least not on a Mac). You hear a beep.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I would be interested to know what is actually happening and how to fix this in Mathematica （if that's fixable).

Comment: My first guess is that `$RecursionLimit = Infinity` let your stack grow too large.  (I'm not prepared to crash my *Mathematica* right now.)

Comment: It's the result of a stack overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685413

Comment: Why, exactly, did you do `$RecursionLimit = Infinity`? Were you sure your recursions would terminate when you did this?

Comment: @ilian At least it's not the result of stackoverflow.com. ;-)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Because without that, MMA gives me an errors, and the help file suggests it may solve the problem?

Comment: …and did you pay attention to what the errors said right before you did this? One does not disable safety features so easily unless one has a full understanding of what can go wrong, and how it can go wrong.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `gives the current limit on the number of levels of recursion that the Wolfram Language can use.` Are you referring to this? Mathematica does not really say much...

Comment: "MMA gives me an errors", as you said. Messages should have appeared; what were they?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general unix question. It has little (nothing?) to do with Mathematica / Wolfram Language.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, they did pick a great name for the site. @Chen Perhaps a non-recursive form like  `tot += Nest[Mod[6 #^2 + 10 # + 3, primes[[i]]] &, a[1], 10^5 - 1];` may work better.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `"Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Mod[6a[98983-1]^2+10a[98983-1]+3,primes[[i]]]."`

Comment: What is so magical about the value of a[10000] for any prime p? Why won't a[1000], which is readily calculated, do?

Comment: @m_goldberg I am not sure what you are asking, but this is Problem 492 if insterested https://projecteuler.net/problem=492

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing So are you blaming this is a unix problem? Why the same(similar) thing happens for windows as well??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kernel crashed after $RecursionLimit = Infinity](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85470/kernel-crashed-after-recursionlimit-infinity)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @ilian , this is now better using a `Nest` instead of the recursive approach.

```
Block[
    {a, primes, tot},

    primes = Select[Range[10^9, 10^9 + 10^3], PrimeQ];
    tot = 0;
    Do[
        tot += Nest[Mod[6 #^2 + 10 # + 3, primes[[i]]] &, 1, 10^(15) - 1];
        , {i, Length@primes}
    ];
    tot
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Here is an even better version:

```
Block[ {a, primes},

    primes = Select[Range[10^9, 10^9 + 10^3], PrimeQ];

        Tr@Table[
        Nest[Mod[6 #^2 + 10 # + 3, primes[[i]]] &, 1, 10^(15) - 1],
        {i, Length[primes]}
        ]

] // AbsoluteTiming
```